# Check if row number increases, Excel

Tags: excel, row

I'm looking for a way or ideas (*preferable array solution*), where you can determine if the numbers in a row increases.

The excel formula should give me "True" for the following sequence, since I want it to exclude #N/A values.

Example:

```
0,22    0,275   0,3162  0,36    #N/A    0,46    0,52
```

Notice:
I saw an reddit post ["Formula to detect if row values are increasing?"](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/2ydfwc/formula_to_detect_if_row_values_are_increasing/) with a similar question. I liked the idea and I have tried to use it with my numbers, but don't get the formula to work/understand it fully.

Comment: if your numbers are in A1:A7 for example, you could do something like 
    = SUM( SIGN( A2:A7 - A1:A6 ) ) = COUNT( A1:A7 ) - 1 
and confirm with Ctrl+Shift+Enter to get an array formula. I'm not quite sure how you can deal with the N/As though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if it can be done in one array formula, because the possibility to have N/A values causes some additional complexity. I can suggest a solution with a helper column though. Say your list of values is in A1:A7, then you can get the sign of the difference between the value in A2 and the value in A1 as follows:

```
= IF( ISNUMBER( A2 ), SIGN( A2 - LOOKUP( 2, 1 /  ISNUMBER( A$1:A1 ), A$1:A1 ) ), 0 )
```

if you put this formula in B2, you can drag this down to B7. Now if you compare the sum of B2:B7 with the number of increases you expect, you have your answer:

```
= SUM( B2:B7 ) = COUNT( A1:A7 ) - 1
```

Refer to [this very helpful page](http://exceljet.net/formula/get-value-of-last-non-empty-cell) to get an explanation of how to get the last non-blank (c.q. numeric) value in a range.